# Scala returning Some(.) to Freemarker

Tags: scala, templates, freemarker

I have the following scala and freemarker code:

```
    val cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_23)
    cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("/Users/simonshapiro/IdeaProjects/Neo4EmbeddedTest/src/main/scala-2.11/informationModel/kernel/templates"))
    cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8")
    cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER)
    val template = cfg.getTemplate("test.ftl")
    val out = new StringWriter
    val data = new mutable.HashMap[String, Any]
    data("name") = "fred"
    data("age") = 27
    template.process(data, out)
    println(out.toString)
```

test.ftl contains:

```
Hi ${name}(${age})

one two three
```

The output from this short program is:

```
Hi Some(fred)(Some(27))

one two three
```

How should get the output without the Some(.) text surrounding the string values from the generated template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Freemarker uses `map.get("key")` to extract parameter inside template.
`new mutable.HashMap` supports `get("key")` function but it returns `Option[Any]` instead of value itself.

I suggest you use general `java.util.HashMap` instead.
For example you can convert your map to java using:

```
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
  map.asJava
```

Answer (score 1):

FreeMarker maps objects to the template language types via an `ObjectWrapper`. So you could extend `DefaultObjectWrapper` to wrap `Some`-s specially, and then set your own `ObjectWrapper` via `Configuration.setObjectWrapper(ObjectWrapper)`. Note that `DefaultObjectWrapper` already extends `BeansWrapper` by adding some specially treated classes, so you can get the idea from the source of it.