# Listing Scala Map values inside FreeMarker template fails

Tags: java, scala, dictionary, freemarker

I am using Freemarker v 2.3.32  and trying to list out the values of a map inside a free marker template. But my unit test fails with the following error:

freemarker.core.NonStringOrTemplateOutputException: For "${...}" content: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), or "template output" , but this has evaluated to a method+sequence (wrapper: f.e.b.SimpleMethodModel):
[info] ==> v  [in template "test.ftl" at line 22, column 11]

Here's my code:

test.ftl:

```
<ul>
<#list params as k,v>
    <li>${v}</li>
<#else>
   <p>Empty map</p>
</#list>
</ul>
```

```
  def sampleHtmlTemplateWithMap(): util.Map[String, Any] = {
    val data = Map("param1" -> "artifact1",
      "param2" -> "artifact2")
    val root = new mutable.HashMap[String, Any];
    root("params") = data
    root.asJava
  }
```

In the unit test, I do the following:

```
      val out = new StringWriter
      testTemplate.process(sampleHtmlTemplateWithMap, out)
```

I can print Scala Array elements, string elements etc. without any issues. But I can't seem to access Map values in the FTL. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

When I do the following , I get the same error.

```
<#list params?values as v>
    <li>${v}</li>
<#else>
   <p>Empty map</p>
</#list>
</ul>
```

However when I try the keys, I see a whole bunch of Scala.collections methods, and no error this time! But that's not what I want

```
<#list params?keys as k>
    <li>${k}</li>
<#else>
   <p>Empty map</p>
</#list>
</ul>
```

Also please note I can access the Map elements individually in the FTL if I specify the keys  i.e.

```
${params["param1"]}
```

And it returns

```
Some(artifact1)
```

And I can see the whole map getting printed when I do:

```
${params}
```

as

```
Map(param1 -> artifact1, param2 -> artifact2)
```

Comment: Is it due to the fact there's a Scala map inside the "root" Scala map that's been converted to Java map?  Does this apply to my problem here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34273574/1452348

Answer (score 0):

Please note, that you haven't converted the inner `data` map into Java Map:

```scala
val data = Map("param1" -> "artifact1",
      "param2" -> "artifact2")
```

(you only applied `.asJava` to the `root` map). Maybe that is the problem here. If not, then I'd pay closer attention to the error you are getting, namely "Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean)". Sounds, like FreeMarker wants to only see simple types (and not maps) here.

But, in addition to that, trying to marry Scala code with Java-focused libraries like FreeMarker, is a recipe for problems like this. You might consider using Twirl instead of Freemarker for a convenient and type-safe templating solution.

Comment: I already tried using as `.asJava` on inner map too. That actually results in a bunch of newer errors. I'll check out Twirl, thanks!